# create thumbnail in php and show without saving

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I have array for images

```
$images[
'image1.jpg',
'image2.jpg',
'image3.jpg',
'image4.jpg',
'image5.jpg',
'image6.jpg',
'image7.jpg',
 .....
'image2500.jpg'
];
```

This is my loop where i show images

```
<?php foreach($images as $img) { ?>
    <img src = "path_to_my_image/<?=$img;?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Everything works good, but in my array sometime it can be 2500 - 3000 images and it work so slow.

how can i create thumbnail in my loop without saving and show?
or
how can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: using php to generate  a thumbnail of each image will probably make the whole process slower

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be compressing the images!
Here is a free trial for an optimization service, but many exist and it's possible to code your own.

https://kraken.io/web-interface

And here is a PHP package to do it at run time if necessary!

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a thumbnail, using PHP, for each image without saving that thumbnail then you could try a simple script like this.

```
<?php
    /* simplethumb.php */
    $file=!empty( $_GET['file'] ) ? $_GET['file'] : false;
    $percent=!empty( $_GET['percent'] ) ? $_GET['percent'] : 10;


    try{
        if( !$file ) throw new Exception('Source file does not exist or cannot be found');
        $source = @imagecreatefromjpeg( $file );

        if( $source && file_exists( $file ) ){
            clearstatcache();

            list( $w, $h, $t, $a ) = getimagesize( $file );
            $nw = $w * ($percent/100);
            $nh = $h * ($percent/100);

            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $nw, $nh );
            @imagecopyresized( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h );

            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            @imagejpeg( $thumb );
            @imagedestroy( $thumb );
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request',true,400);
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

And for your loop

```
foreach($images as $img) {
    echo "<img src='simplethumb.php?file=path_to_my_image/{$img}&percent=25' />";
}
```